# Convert Date Time to IST

Tags: c#

I want to convert the date time to "Indian Standard Time", so i used the following code :-

```
public static TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = 
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Indian Standard Time");

writer.WriteLine("{0} {1}", indianTime.ToLongTimeString(),
                indianTime.ToLongDateString());
```

The above code gives me error :-

> System.TimeZoneNotFoundException: The time zone ID 'Indian Standard
>   Time' was not found on the local computer.

How to solve this error or is there any another method to achieve this?

Comment: It's just typo...use "India Standard Time"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use "India Standard Time" instead of "India**n**". Please refer to [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154758.aspx) for a list of the time zone descriptions.

Comment: "India" instead of "India**n**".

Answer (score 2):

**Put field as:**

```
private static TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
```

**then use:**

```
DateTime indianTime =  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, INDIAN_ZONE);
```

to get the time as needed.